# aligning columns in a text file

Tags: r, alignment

Is there any way, using R, I can straighten up these first 3 columns and just to have one space between each. Currently, its more like a "tab".

Here is the content of the original file:

```
anim      sire      dam
4736    2A0584  2W151
4737    2A0584  2W151
4738    2A0584  2W151
4739    2A0584  2W151
4963    1W648   1W174
4964    1W648   1W174
```

I would like the contents of a new file to contain the original data, but to be like these columns with only a single space between each value

```
anim sire   dam
4736 2A0584 2W151
4737 2A0584 2W151
4738 2A0584 2W151
4739 2A0584 2W151
4963 1W648 1W174
4964 1W648 1W174
```

Comment: can you straighten these data up in your post so we know what you mean?

Comment: @mdsumner, Thanks! I have just straighten it up. Is it any better now?

Comment: what do you mean straighten up? What's the context for what you are trying to do here?

Comment: I was trying to align the columns and the space between each space to be just one space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that text is in a file as you present it here and you want a file with single spaces, then read it in:

```
 x <- read.table("f.txt", header = TRUE)
```

Now write it out with the desired options (no row names, and no quotes):

```
 write.table(x, "outf.txt", sep = " ", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```